# How to groupBy and remove repeated objects

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin

I have this Item class:

```
data class Product(val id: Long, val name: String, val region: Long)
```

Given a list `List<Product>`:

```
Product(1, "Product 1", 1)
Product(1, "Product 1", 1)
Product(1, "Product 1", 2)
Product(2, "Product 2", 1)
```

As you can see the same product can be added many times to same Region. I want to groupBy region like `productList.groupBy { it.region }` but in the generated map entries I want to remove the products that has the same Id.

Comment: Use a Set not a List

Comment: hint: what does your equals method looks like?

Comment: @Yayo If the product belong to different regions, then each Product Object will be different and Set can be used right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
productList.groupBy { it.region }.mapValues { it.distinctBy { it.id } }
```

[`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html):

> Returns a new map with entries having the keys of this map and the values obtained by applying the transform function to each entry in this Map.

[`distinctBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html):

> Returns a list containing only elements from the given collection having distinct keys returned by the given selector function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this we need to override `hash` and `equals` method  in `ProductInfo` class then apply below stream api

```
 Map<Integer,List<ProductInfor>> map=list.stream()
.distinct()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductInfo::getId,Collectors.toList()))
```

for complete code go through below-

```
   import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

class ProductInfo{
private Integer id;
private String product;
private Integer region;

public Integer getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getProduct(){
    return product;
}

public Integer getRegion(){
    return region;
}

public ProductInfo(Integer id,String product,Integer region){

    this.id=id;
    this.product=product;
    this.region=region;
}

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        ProductInfo that = (ProductInfo)o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), that.getId()) && Objects.equals(getProduct(), that.getProduct()) && Objects
            .equals(getRegion(), that.getRegion());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getProduct(), getRegion());
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "id="+this.getId()+" product="+this.getProduct()+" region="+getRegion();
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<ProductInfo> list=Arrays.asList(new ProductInfo(1,"product1",1),new ProductInfo(1,"product1",1),new ProductInfo(2,"product2",2));
        System.out.println(list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductInfo::getId,Collectors.toList())));
    }
}
```